# Restricting the number of the same log via fluentD

Tags: fluentd

Use case: Set the maximum number of messages (within a timeframe) to be sent to a target service.

Example.
We collect logs from service X which has these kind of logs:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.310Z","level":"INFO","message":"This is some event"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.315Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn abc123"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.325Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn abc123"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.327Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn abc123"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.335Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn xyz123"}
```

As you can see the same warning (abc123) was logged multiple time by the service within 12ms.
What I want is to send only one from them.

So fluentD should forward these to the target service:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.310Z","level":"INFO","message":"This is some event"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.315Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn abc123"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-30T13:00:00.335Z","level":"WARN","message":"This is warn xyz123"}
```

Which timestamp to use or to have a counter doesn't matter for me.

Is there a filter,plugin for this use case? Something like where I can set a regex rule for the messages(for deciding whether more messages should be considered as equal) and a timeframe?

Comment: That's an interesting use-case! So, it's like storing events for a small timeframe (window) and then send only the unique ones, right? I think you could make use of buffer and [exec](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/exec) plugins i.e. store events in a buffer for the interval, let exec to filter the unique ones and pass those on. It's just an idea. You do need to experiment though.

Answer (score 0):

In fluentd one may try the throttle plugin https://github.com/rubrikinc/fluent-plugin-throttle with a `message` key as a `group_key` (not sure about performance in this case tho).

In FluentBit you can use a built-in SQL stream processor and write a `SELECT` with `WINDOW` and `GROUP BY` statements: https://docs.fluentbit.io/stream-processing/getting_started/fluent_bit_sql#select-statement.